# PHP DOM append child with new line

Tags: php, dom

My name Rithy.

I don't know how to add new line before appending a new node or element in the xml.

**My php:**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->formatOutput = true;

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

$dom->load($xml_file);

$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

$newelement_seg = $dom->createElement('seg');

$data = $dom->createTextNode(" text 2 ");  

$newelement_seg->appendChild($data);

$body->appendChild($newelement_seg);

$dom->save($xml_file);
```

**XML Before append a new child:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <seg>
        text 1
    </seg>
</body>
</xml>
```

**XML after append a new child:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <seg>
        text 1
    </seg>
    <seg>
        text 2
    </seg>
</body>
</xml>
```

**But I want:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <body>
        <seg>
            text 1
        </seg>
        <seg>
            text 2
        </seg>
    </body>
</xml>
<hr/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question would be a lot more legible if it were formatted correctly. And honestly, clicking the "code" button would have been far easier on your end than replacing all the angle-brackets with HTML entities and double-spacing everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish?

By setting `preserveWhiteSpace` to `true` (unnecessary; that's the default), you are telling libxml not to ignore text nodes that are composed only of white space. Yet, at the same time, you're trying to pretty format the XML file, which to be really pretty requires whitespace nodes.

Then, even ignoring white space, you have to realize the whitespace inside the `<seg>` tags is significant; libxml will not remove those; if you force a line break after `text 1`, in the next line the `</seg>` closing tag must not be indented, otherwise the content of the text node inside the tag would differ.

Your code gives me this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<seg>
  text 1  
</seg>
<seg> text 2 </seg></body>
```

Since you're telling libxml that whitespace is significant, it cannot put a line break after the second `</seg>`, otherwise it'd be creating another text node.

If you say `$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <seg>
  text 1  
</seg>
  <seg> text 2 </seg>
</body>
```

The tags are indented, but libxml still cannot do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <seg>
    text 1  
  </seg>
  <seg>
    text 2
  </seg>
</body>
```

because it would be changing the content of the text nodes inside `<seg>`.

You might want to try [tidy](http://pt.php.net/tidy), though I'm not sure it'll do what you want.

Comment: OK, That's fixed by problem!
Thank you alot!
For the text in the seg tag, I could do it.

Answer (score 12):

**TO SUMMARIZE THE ANSWERS GIVEN:**

1. you have to set formatOutput to true
2. you have to set ignoreWhiteSpace to false

ie:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->load($myxmlfile);
```

Answer (score 3):

Perfect solution. It's working. Here is the code that I have used:

```
       //create new document object
        $dom_object = new DOMDocument(); 

        //load xml file
        $xml_file_path = get_template_directory()."/flash/playlist.xml";
        $dom_object->formatOutput = true;    
        $dom_object->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom_object->load($xml_file_path);
```